# Prove that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln (1+x)}{x}=1$ by Taylor series.

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

I want to prove that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln (1+x)}{x}=1$ by Taylor series. I have get to the step: $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln (1+x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x-\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{x^3}{3}-\dfrac{x^4}{4}+\cdots}{x}$$

Next, when $x\neq0$, $\frac{x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots}{x}=\frac{1}{x}\left(x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots\right)=1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}-\cdots$. This is valid because $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^n}{n}$ converges for every $x\neq 0$ near $0$, and then we can multiply a constant $\frac{1}{x}$ inside it. However, how can I rigorously and easily say that $\lim_{x\to 0}(1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}-\cdots)=1$?

Comment: Direct substitution?

Comment: It involves infinitely many terms, that's the problem.

Comment: @Eric, the function defined by that power series $f(x) = 1 - \frac{x}{2} + \frac{x^2}{3} - \cdots$ is continuous, so $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = f(0)$, which, by Taylor's theorem, is the constant term in the power series, namely $1$..

Comment: @Eric :This figure may help you ....https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3fp5q4tan9

Comment: @Eric: For $|x|<1$ you can use $|x|^n<|x|$ or $-x<x^n<x$ and therefore $-x\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}n < \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^n}{n} < x\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$. So you see what has to happen for $x\to 0$.

Comment: @Khosrotash Clearly not. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can be pretty brutal about this and just expand with the triangle inequality:

\begin{align*}
\left\lvert x - \frac{x^2}2 + \frac{x^3}3 - \cdots\right\rvert \le x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots = \frac{x}{1 - x} \to 0
\end{align*}

as $x \to 0$.

---

That being said, it sorta misses the point to use Taylor series like this*. The limit you're looking at is the definition of
$$\left.\frac{d}{dx}\bigl(\ln(1 + x)\bigr)\right\vert_{x=0}$$
which you would need to compute in order to even know the Taylor series.

* If you've only defined log via Taylor series, or every used the derivative of log to compute the Taylor series.

Comment: Hmm.. how to prove $\left.\frac{d}{dx}\bigl(\ln(1 + x)\bigr)\right\vert_{x=0}$ in your context?

Comment: It depends on how log is defined. A standard thing is that it's the inverse of the exponential, and you use the implicit function theorem. Another standard thing is to define it via $x \mapsto \int_1^x dt/t$ and use the FTC.

Comment: I gain the power series of $x\mapsto \ln(1+x)$ by integrating $\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots$ and substitute $(-x)$ into the result $\ln(1-x)$.

Comment: Ok, well that's another good way to get it and it's not circular.

Answer (score 0):

By the definition of the derivative at $x=0$
$$
\log(1+x)=x+o(x)
$$
Hence
$$
\log(1+x)/x\to1.
$$
as $x\to0$.

Answer (score -1):

$\dfrac{\log(1+x) -\log(1)}{x} =$

$ \log'(t) =1/t,$  $1< t<1+x.$

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} (1/t) =1.$

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{\log(1+x)-\log(x)}{x} = 1.$

Used: Mean Value Theorem.